# Angular and nested recursion

Tags: angular, recursion, nested

I'd like to know if nested recursion is possible with Angular components.
I mean with "nested recursivity" a component A that use a component B that use itself the component A back. I want to use this to display a hierarchical structure like a folder tree.
Recursivity works perfectly with only one component that reuse itself. But as soon as I remove a part of the code to put it in a second component, it no longer works.

this is the working code :

```
<div class="folder">
    <div class="folder-title">Folder</div>
    <div class="folder-name">
        <span>{{this.folder.name}}</span>
        <lib-sub-folders-indicator [subFoldersIndicator]="subFoldersIndicator" (click)="OnClick()"></lib-sub-folders-indicator>
    </div>

**    <div class="folder-subfolders" *ngIf="HasSubFolders() && !subFoldersClosed">
        <lib-folder *ngFor="let myfolder of folder.folders" [folder]="myfolder"></lib-folder>
    </div>**
</div>
```

This is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLEmt.png)

This is the wrong working code :

```
<div class="folder">
    <div class="folder-title">Folder</div>
    <div class="folder-name">
        <span>{{this.folder.name}}</span>
        <lib-sub-folders-indicator [subFoldersIndicator]="subFoldersIndicator" (click)="OnClick()"></lib-sub-folders-indicator>
    </div>
    **<lib-folders *ngIf="HasSubFolders() && !subFoldersClosed" [folders]="folder.folders"></lib-folders>**
</div>
```

And the second component :

```
<div class="folder-subfolders">
    <lib-folder *ngFor="let myfolder of folders" [folder]="myfolder"></lib-folder>
</div>
```

The console display this message :
2 folder.component.html:9  NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 'FolderComponent' component template).
If the 'ngIf' is an Angular control flow directive, please make sure that either the 'NgIf' directive or the 'CommonModule' is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.

Does anyone know if Angular is capable of handling nested recursion ?

Thanks for reading

My environment :

Angular CLI: 16.1.8
Node: 18.13.0
Package Manager: pnpm 8.12.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.2.12
animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Comment: Double stars " ** " are not in the original code. It might have done a bold effect.

Comment: "Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'" is because you don't import the CommonModule (or NgIf). If you're using standalone components add it in the imports array, is you are not using standalone components import in the module where you have declared the component

Comment: It was something like that.
My route was just pointing the folder component without loading the module.
Thank Eliseo

So I have the answer : Yes, nested recursion is possible with Angular

Answer (score 1):

My route was just pointing the folder component without loading the module.
So I have the answer :
Yes, nested recursion is possible with Angular.